How do I store an attribute of type "Object" in Gutenberg?
i created a custom attribute with name "mediaItem".
attributes.js
const attributes = {
    mediaItem: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
            type: 'none',
            attachment: 'scroll',
            size: 'contain',
        },
    },

In my custom component i want to update this value.
I found this example:

So i created this in my component:
const [mediaDimensions, setMediaDimensions] = useState(mediaItem);

const updateImageObj = (key, value) => {
    setMediaDimensions({ ...mediaDimensions, [key]: value });
};

Unfortunately, nothing happend. My console.log output the same data.
Next i tried this example:
const updateImageObj = (key, value) => {
    // setMediaDimensions({ ...mediaDimensions, [key]: value });

    let oldObject = mediaItem;
    mediaItem[key] = value;
    setAttributes({ image: oldObject });

    // console.log(mediaItem);
};

In my console.log the attribute was updated but the "Update" Button still disabled and i have no opportunity to save my state.

What am I doing wrong when saving an object?
